# What is the name of this hexagon geometric shape?

Tags: geometry, terminology

[image: Geometric shape]

Does this irregular hexagon that looks like this has some name given?

Comment: I'm not aware of any standard name for this shape

Comment: I'd call it an _ortho-bitruncated square_, following the taxonomy of Johnson solids.

Comment: I'd call it a hexagon and say no more.

Comment: I don't know the name, but it was a common shape used for larger blocks in monolithic sites (ancient structures).